# SQL subqueries return records, but the main query as a whole returns zero rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

This query fetches zero rows as a whole. I've tried running each of the sub-queries separately, and each works fine.

The main table `ITEMS` contains all items in the inventory. The table `ISSUED` contains `item IDs` which have been issued out from the main store.

I'm running two sub-queries in this main query. One which fetches the count of all items in the inventory which were entered into the stock, on a given day and haven't been issued, and the other which fetches the count of all items which were entered into the inventory on that day, but were issued out on the same day.

I need to get the sum of both these counts of items grouped by item name.

```
SELECT ITEMS.ITEM AS ITEM,
   ( IFNULL(Arr1.TAG_COUNT, 0)
     + IFNULL(Arr2.TAG_COUNT, 0) ) AS TAG_COUNT 
 FROM   ((SELECT ITEMS.ITEM      AS ITEM,
           Count(ITEMS.ID) AS TAG_COUNT
    FROM   ITEMS
    WHERE  ITEMS.DT_ARRIVAL = '2019-01-01'
           AND ITEMS.ID NOT IN (SELECT ISSUED.ID
                                FROM   ISSUED)
    GROUP  BY ITEMS.ITEM) AS Arr1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ITEMS.ITEM      AS ITEM,
                      Count(ITEMS.ID) AS TAG_COUNT
               FROM   ITEMS
                      LEFT JOIN ISSUED
                             ON ISSUED.ID = ITEMS.ID
               WHERE  ITEMS.ID IN (SELECT ISSUED.ID
                                   FROM   ISSUED)
                      AND ISSUED.DATE = '2019-01-01'
               GROUP  BY ITEMS.ITEM) AS Arr2
           ON Arr2.ITEM = Arr1.ITEM
    LEFT JOIN ITEMS
           ON ITEMS.ITEM = Arr1.ITEM)
GROUP  BY ITEMS.ITEM
```

Comment: Have different table aliases for each ITEMS instance, to make code clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have made this much more complicated than you need to if your requirements are correct. From what you say you need

1) Items that arrived on 2019-01-01 and have not been shipped.

2) Items that arrived on 2019-01-01 and were shipped on the same day.

There's a number of issues with your current SQL, but you can get your result much more simply with a simple OR clause:

```
SELECT A.ITEM, COUNT(*)
FROM ITEMS A
WHERE A.DT_ARRIVAL = '2019-01-01'
AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ISSUED B WHERE A.ID = B.ID)
     OR (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ISSUED C WHERE A.ID = C.ID
         AND C.ISSUED_DT = A.DT_ARRIVAL)
  )
GROUP BY A.ITEM
```

Let me know if I've missed something, but that seems to cover the requirements as listed.

One of the problems with your current query is you're doing a left join from rows that meet your first requirement, to rows that meet your second. They should never join and so you'll never get the rows/values for your second requirement. Overall I think you've confused yourself using too many unnecessary sub-queries and joins, and then made it even more confusing by not using unique alias's when you've referenced the same table multiple times.

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm. I feel stupid I wasn't able to think of that.